# Windows nginx + nodejs API, proxy_connect_timeout reached

Tags: windows, node.js, express, nginx, restify

I have an RESTful API relying on nodejs and restify. 
It is being served on port 8989.

I have nginx listening to port 444 and I have a proxy pass like this one

```
    location /v1/
    {       
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8989;
    }
```

Any call to something like

```
http://localhost:444/v1/hello
```

works fine, but only the first time. The second time it responds exactly 60 seconds later.
If you cancel the request and try it again, then it works again, but the next time will be the same. So, after each successful call there is one that is delayed 60 seconds.

It only happens when the services are running on nodejs. I have tried changing the API framework to express and Percolator js and there is the same issue. However, when I try with a C# NancyFx API this issue doesn't happen.

Also, if you try to access the services directly, that is something like

```
http://localhost:8989/v1/hello
```

It always looks just fine.

After looking at the headers that were being sent to the retify server, I found the next two things, when calling it through the nginx proxy, there are this two headers:

```
GET /v1/menu/esp.json HTTP/1.0
connection: close
```

When calling it directly, there are this two headers

```
GET /v1/menu/esp.json HTTP/1.1
connection: keep-alive
```

Given this, I thought that the restify server was delaying the next call because it was too soon to give access to a new one.

So I did what it was necessary to make nginx to pass exactly the same headers. The configuration then was:

```
upstream services
{
    server localhost:8989;
    keepalive 100;
}

server {
    listen       444;
    server_name  localhost;

    location /v1/
    {       
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host localhost:8989;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep_alive;
        proxy_pass http://services;
    }
}
```

I have got it to pass exactly the same headers to the nodejs restify server, but the behaviour is exactly the same than before.

I'm using the windows versions of both, nodejs and nginx.

### EDIT

I patched it using

```
proxy_connect_timeout 2s;
```

As someone else did here http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?15,239760,247173

It seems to be an already known issue.

Comment: What is the point of listen in another port?, why not call directly to 8989?

Comment: Did you try it using another server_name and listen port? (configuring your hosts file according to this).

Comment: The main reason to pass all the calls proxied is to avoid Cross-origin resource sharing. And yes, I tried with different sever_name's and ports.